# Generic C# function issue creating

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create generic function like below it can be static or not but the case is i want to be reusable with  what i have one is below.

When i controller i want to use my "generic function" it get this VScode error

```
The type 'API.Entity.List' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'AnnotateOrder<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'API.Entity.List' to 'API.Helpers.IOrder'. [API]csharp(CS0311)
```

I want to be able to pass there as `<T> List<Item> or <List<List>>` all listed below

Helper class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using API.Entity;
using API.Interfaces;

namespace API.Helpers {
    public interface IOrder {
        int Order { get; set; }
       
    }
    
    public class AnnotateOrder<T> : List<T> where T : IOrder {

        static public List<T> AnnotatedOrder (List<T> ent) {
            if (ent != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ent.Count; i++) {
                    ent[i].Order = i;
                }
            }
            return ent;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateListOrder(Guid id, [FromBody] List<List> list)
        {
            var board = await _boardRepository.GetBoardAsync(id);

            var newBoardListOrder = new AnnotateOrder<List>().AnnotatedOrder(list);
            

            if (board.Lists.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var newList in newBoardListOrder)
                {
                    foreach (var oldList in board.Lists)
                    {
                        if (oldList.Id == newList.Id)
                        {
                            oldList.Id = oldList.Id;
                            oldList.Title = newList.Title;
                            oldList.Order = newList.Order;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            _boardRepository.UpdateBoard(board);
            if (await _boardRepository.SaveChanges()) return NoContent();

            return BadRequest("Failed to update list");
        }
```

Entites that i want to pass as 'T'

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace API.Entity
{
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public List List { get; set; }
        public Guid ListId { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace API.Entity
{
    public class List
    {   
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public Board Board { get; set; }
        public Guid BoardId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function requires `T` to implement `IOrder`

```
public class AnnotateOrder<T> : List<T> where T : IOrder
```

If this is not done, the error gets thrown at compile time. It shows clearly that the interface is not implemented in your `List` type.

> The type 'API.Entity.List' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
> generic type or method 'AnnotateOrder'. There is no implicit
> reference conversion from 'API.Entity.List' to 'API.Helpers.IOrder'.
> [API]csharp(CS0311)

Since `List` already contains all required interface properties, it can be simply done by adding it:

```
public class List : IOrder
{
    ...
```